# Creating a draggable, resizable box with rotation handle in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a project where I need to create a box using D3.js, and I want to implement the following functionality:

The main box should be created using the  element.
On each corner of the box, I want to add a small circle that will act as a scale and rotate anchor.
When the user clicks and drags on any of these corner circles, the box should scale up or down based on the mouse movement.
If the user holds down the "Shift" key while dragging a corner circle, it should trigger rotation instead of scaling.

When dragging anywhere else on the box (not on the corner circles), the box should be dragged

I've started with the basic box creation using D3.js, but I'm struggling with integrating the drag, scale, and rotate functionalities. Could someone provide guidance or a code example to achieve this interactive behavior?

Here's my current code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Rotating Rectangle with D3</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Set up SVG container
      const svgWidth = 400;
      const svgHeight = 400;

      const svg = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight);

      // Set up rectangle
      let rectWidth = 100;
      let rectHeight = 50;

      const rectangle = svg
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", (svgWidth - rectWidth) / 2)
        .attr("y", (svgHeight - rectHeight) / 2)
        .attr("width", rectWidth)
        .attr("height", rectHeight)
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr(
          "transform",
          "rotate(0, " + svgWidth / 2 + ", " + svgHeight / 2 + ")"
        );

      // Set up rotation anchor
      const rotationAnchor = svg
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", svgWidth / 2)
        .attr("cy", (svgHeight - rectHeight) / 2)
        .attr("r", 8)
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .call(d3.drag().on("drag", rotateHandler));

      // Set up resize anchor for width
      const widthResizeAnchor = svg
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", (svgWidth + rectWidth) / 2)
        .attr("cy", (svgHeight - rectHeight) / 2)
        .attr("r", 8)
        .attr("fill", "green")
        .call(d3.drag().on("drag", widthResizeHandler));

      // Set up resize anchor for height
      const heightResizeAnchor = svg
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", (svgWidth + rectWidth) / 2)
        .attr("cy", (svgHeight + rectHeight) / 2)
        .attr("r", 8)
        .attr("fill", "purple")
        .call(d3.drag().on("drag", heightResizeHandler));

      // Drag behavior for rotation anchor
      function rotateHandler() {
        const mouseX = d3.event.x;
        const mouseY = d3.event.y;

        // Calculate angle of rotation based on mouse position
        const angle =
          Math.atan2(mouseY - svgHeight / 2, mouseX - svgWidth / 2) *
          (180 / Math.PI);

        // Update rectangle's rotation around its center
        rectangle.attr(
          "transform",
          "translate(" +
            svgWidth / 2 +
            "," +
            svgHeight / 2 +
            ") rotate(" +
            angle +
            ") translate(" +
            -(svgWidth / 2) +
            "," +
            -(svgHeight / 2) +
            ")"
        );
      }

      // Drag behavior for width resize anchor
      function widthResizeHandler() {
        const mouseX = d3.event.x;

        // Calculate the new width
        rectWidth = mouseX - rectangle.attr("x");

        // Update rectangle's width
        rectangle.attr("width", rectWidth);
      }

      // Drag behavior for height resize anchor
      function heightResizeHandler() {
        const mouseY = d3.event.y;

        // Calculate the new height
        rectHeight = mouseY - rectangle.attr("y");

        // Update rectangle's height
        rectangle.attr("height", rectHeight);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

interactive box usoing d3.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done a little program to help you to begin. I think you could easily adapt my program to your solution .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>D3.js Resizable and Draggable Box</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    svg {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .box {
      fill: lightblue;
      stroke: #333;
    }
    .handle {
      fill: white;
      stroke: #333;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
  const width = 400;
  const height = 400;
  const handleRadius = 5;
  
 
  // Create SVG container
  const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


  // Create resizable and draggable box with handles
  const box = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("class", "box")
    .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragStart)
      .on("drag", dragging)      
   );
   box.data([
    {startX: +box.attr("x")},
    {startY: +box.attr("y")}
    ]);


  function dragStart(event, d) {

   // box.raise().classed("active", true);
    d.startX = event.x;
    d.startY = event.y;
    d.boxX = +box.attr("x");
    d.boxY = +box.attr("y");
  }

  function dragging(event, d) {

    const newX = Math.max(0, Math.min(width - +box.attr("width"), event.x));
    const newY = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - +box.attr("height"), event.y));
    const dx = d.startX - event.x;
    const dy = d.startY - event.y;

    d.startX = event.x;
    d.startY = event.y;
    box.attr("x", d.boxX - dx);
    box.attr("y", d.boxY - dy);
    d.boxX = +box.attr("x");
    d.boxY = +box.attr("y");

    // Update handles' positions xhen dragging box
    handles.data([
      { x: d.boxX, y: d.boxY ,cursor: "nw-resize"},
      { x: d.boxX + +box.attr("width"), y: d.boxY, cursor: "ne-resize" },
      { x: d.boxX, y: d.boxY + +box.attr("height"), cursor: "sw-resize" },
      { x: d.boxX + +box.attr("width"), y: d.boxY + +box.attr("height") , cursor: "se-resize"}
    ])
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  }

  //function dragEnd(event) {
  //  box.classed("active", false);
  //}

  const handles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data([
      { x: 100, y: 100, cursor: "nw-resize" },
      { x: 200, y: 100, cursor: "ne-resize" },
      { x: 100, y: 200, cursor: "sw-resize" },
      { x: 200, y: 200, cursor: "se-resize" }
    ])
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "handle")
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
    .attr("r", handleRadius)
    .style("cursor", d => d.cursor)
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", handleDragStart)
      .on("drag", handleDragging)
    );
    

let rotating = false;

  d3.select("body")
    .on("keydown", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Shift") {
        rotating = true;
      }
    })
    .on("keyup", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Shift") {
        rotating = false;
      }
    });
    
  function handleDragStart(event, d) {
        
    d.startX = event.x;
    d.startY = event.y;
    d.initialBox = {
      x: +box.attr("x"),
      y: +box.attr("y"),
      width: +box.attr("width"),
      height: +box.attr("height"),
      rotation: +box.attr("transform")?.split("(")[1].split(")")[0] || 0
    };

  }

  function handleDragging(event, d) {

    const dx = event.x - d.startX;
    const dy = event.y - d.startY;

 if (rotating) {
      const angle = Math.atan2(event.y - height / 2, event.x - width / 2);
      //const transform = "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ") rotate(" + (angle * (180 / Math.PI) + 90) + ") translate(" + (-width / 2) + "," + (-height / 2) + ")";
      //select the circle coord as canter rotation
      const transform = "rotate(" +  (angle * (180 / Math.PI) + 90) + "," + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      
      box.attr("transform", transform);

      //box.attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2}) rotate(${angle * (180 / Math.PI) + 90}) translate(${-width / 2},${-height / 2})`);
      
      handles.attr("transform", (d, i) => box.attr("transform"));

    } else {
    if (d.cursor.includes("nw")) {
      box.attr("x", Math.min(d.initialBox.x + d.initialBox.width, Math.max(0, d.initialBox.x + dx)));
      box.attr("y", Math.min(d.initialBox.y + d.initialBox.height, Math.max(0, d.initialBox.y + dy)));
      box.attr("width", Math.max(0, d.initialBox.width - dx));
      box.attr("height", Math.max(0, d.initialBox.height - dy));
    } else if  (d.cursor.includes("se")) {
      box.attr("width", Math.max(0, d.initialBox.width + dx));
      box.attr("height", Math.max(0, d.initialBox.height + dy));
    } else if  (d.cursor.includes("sw")) {
        box.attr("x", Math.min(d.initialBox.x + d.initialBox.width, Math.max(0, d.initialBox.x + dx)));
      box.attr("width", Math.max(0, d.initialBox.width - dx));
      box.attr("height", Math.max(0, d.initialBox.height + dy));

    } else if  (d.cursor.includes("ne")) {
        box.attr("y", Math.min(d.initialBox.y + d.initialBox.height, Math.max(0, d.initialBox.y + dy)));
      box.attr("width", Math.max(0, d.initialBox.width + dx));
      box.attr("height", Math.max(0, d.initialBox.height - dy));
    }
}

    // Update the position of all circles during resizing
    handles.attr("cx", (d, i) => {
        let t = 0;
      if( i == 0){
        t = +box.attr("x");
      } else if(i==1 ){
        t = +box.attr("x") + +box.attr("width");
      } else if (i == 2){
        t = +box.attr("x")
      } else if (i == 3){
        t = +box.attr("x") + +box.attr("width");
      }
      return t;
    })
      .attr("cy", (d, i) => {
      let t = 0;
      if( i == 0)
      {
        t = +box.attr("y");
      } else if( i == 1){
        t = +box.attr("y");
      } else if( i ==2){
        t = +box.attr("y") + +box.attr("height");
      }else if( i == 3){
        t = +box.attr("y") + +box.attr("height");
      }
      return t;
     });
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```